# Salesforce - Execute code without using execute anonymous window

Tags: salesforce

Is there a method by which we can call methods/functions without using developer console-> execute anonymous window.

For ex-
A class is present in org, which can create bulk data. We are thinking to create a page on org and place a button on that page, which will call the method in same way as we do it using developer console->execute anonymous window.

can we do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a VisualForce page with a controller add a button to the page and just run the method on controller no need for execute anonymous or anything. To see some examples on how create Visualforce pages please refer to salesforce documentation [here](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_hello_world.htm) or [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce)

Answer (score 0):

The Tooling and Apex APIs have an execute anonymous function that you can call. Although it sounds like you might want to use the Bulk API in your case.